# regex to extract the number from string

Tags: regex

I have a string like this

```
file-myfle_20130207_094852am.csv
```

how do i go about writing the regex to extract only the numbers

```
20130207094852
```

Comment: `find -name '*.csv' | sed s/[^[:digit:]]//`

Comment: What kind of tool are you using? What are you actually trying to do? (file renaming?)

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Regular expressions don't "extract" anything, they match patterns. If you want to transform your input string to the desired output string, that's a somewhat different thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this (this is pretty common among Regex tutorials)

```
\d+
```

Each group will be the numbers.

Comment: Might want to use * to account for the lack of numbers.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija, no. No number is not a number (which was of interest). Off topic, +5 for `\d+`, fu SO... ;-)

Comment: This is at best incomplete solution. The numbers in the question are separated by `_`.

Comment: @nhahtdh Without a known language to combine them back together.. how do you propose I update my answer?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: That's why I just leave a plain comment. I am curious why no one even ask the OP to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on the question for context.

From a shell:

```
echo file-myfle_20130207_094852am.csv | tr -cd /0-9/
20130207094852
```

With Perl:

```
echo file-myfle_20130207_094852am.csv | perl -pe 's/\D//g'
20130207094852
```